Why isn't the Gaussian blur kernel defined via the cdf?
A 1-D Gaussian blur kernel of size $2k + 1$ is defined as:
$$K = \text{Normalize}([G(-k), \ldots, G(0), \ldots, G(k)])$$
where
$${\displaystyle G(r) = {\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi \sigma ^{2}}}}e^{-{\frac {r^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}}}$$
and
$$\text{Normalize}(v) = \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}.$$
The kernel represents how much nearby samples are weighted in the blur.

However, wouldn't it make more sense to determine the kernel using the cdf (to measure the area under the probability distribution), rather than the pdf? That is,
$$K = \text{Normalize}([A(-k), \ldots, A(0), \ldots, A(k)])$$
where
$$A(x) = \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} G(x + r) \, dr = \text{CDF}(x + 1/2) - \text{CDF}(x - 1/2).$$
